# Create an explicit index from a primary key - Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle11g, primary-key

I was trying to do the following statement:

```
    CREATE INDEX IVMV_Producto_IDX ON PRODUCTO (CODIGO) TABLESPACE TSDATA_IVMV;
```

But it does not work because Oracle already creates it. And i need to create these index on the PRODUCTO's primary key in an explicit way.

The PRODUCTO table was created thereby:

```
    CREATE TABLE PRODUCTO(

     CODIGO VARCHAR(20),

     NOMBRE VARCHAR2(30),

     PRECIO VARCHAR(20),

     CONSTRAINT PRODUCTO_PK PRIMARY KEY(CODIGO)

     ) TABLESPACE TSDATA_IVMV PCTFREE 20 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255;
```

What am i supposed to do? Help me please.

Comment: Why do you need to create the index "in an explicit way"?  If you are merely trying to cause the index to be created in a specific tablespace, you can do that as part of the `create table` without doing a separate `create index`.  If you want separate statements, you'd create the table without the constraint, create the index, then create the constraint with a `using index` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTO (
     CODIGO VARCHAR(20),
     NOMBRE VARCHAR2(30),
     PRECIO VARCHAR(20),
     CONSTRAINT PRODUCTO_PK PRIMARY KEY(CODIGO) USING INDEX (CREATE INDEX IVMV_Producto_IDX ON PRODUCTO (CODIGO) TABLESPACE TSDATA_IVMV)
)
TABLESPACE TSDATA_IVMV PCTFREE 20 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255;

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTO (
     CODIGO VARCHAR(20),
     NOMBRE VARCHAR2(30),
     PRECIO VARCHAR(20)
)
TABLESPACE TSDATA_IVMV PCTFREE 20 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255;

ALTER TABLE PRODUCTO ADD CONSTRAINT PRODUCTO_PK PRIMARY KEY(CODIGO) USING INDEX (CREATE INDEX IVMV_Producto_IDX ON PRODUCTO (CODIGO) TABLESPACE TSDATA_IVMV)
```